# Redirect all traffic through my Raspberry PI

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, routing, linux-networking

I have a Raspberry PI 4B that is doing DNS (PiHole+Bind9), DHCP, Wireguard, ... The RPi is on 192.168.1.2 and it hands out 192.168.1.1 (router) as the default gateway for internet traffic.

My Chromecast (and maybe other devices) are using hardcoded DNS servers, so I want to redirect that traffic back to my own DNS. My router isn't capable to intercept DNS traffic, so the only option is to route all my traffic to the Raspberry Pi and use `iptables` to intercept the DNS requests. I want to specify 192.168.1.2 as the default gateway from the DHCP server and use iptables to forward all traffic (besides DNS) to the router. I know this isn't 100% safe, because users can manually set the gateway to 192.168.1.1 to prevent this. I don't think devices would be smart enough to do this.

I have several questions:

1. Is a Raspberry Pi 4B fast enough to deal with a 1Gbit/s uplink? I have a 1Gbit/s fiber-connection and I am able to reach up to 950Mbit/s in my current setup.
2. How do I setup my RPI to forward all incoming traffic (not meant for 192.168.1.2) to 192.168.1.1?
3. How can I intercept DNS requests (port 53 on TCP/UDP and route it to my DNS on 192.168.1.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It should be capable to work; usually home routers which also are software routers with little HW accel are built upon wa-a-ay less powerful processors than RasPi 4B. But this also depends on many details of configuration. Just try and test it.
2. Just have default route and enable IPv4 forwarding (`sysctl.conf`, `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`) on RPi, that's basically it. Then you'll be able to specify it as default gateway on other systems and it will work. But I don't know default network configuration on RPi, you may need also to disable redirects (in the `sysctl.conf`, where you enabled forwarding, set `net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0` and `net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0`). It may be needed for RPi to not to issue notifications to hosts: "I forwarded this packet for you, but you can do it yourself, use .1.1 directly".
3. This was answered on another site:
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/592042/iptables-redirect-dns-queries
   This is perfectly applicable for your case.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. It only encourages more people to post off-topic.